# Is there any way to check if the checkbox is actually checked by the user

Tags: android, checkbox

Apart from `setOnCheckedChangeListener`, is there any way through which I can check that user has actually touched the screen and checked/unchecked the `checkbox`.

I'm asking this question because my flow is going inside the `setOnCheckedChangeListener` even if the user has not performed the check.

Comment: have you tried onTouch() listener?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take one boolean flag.
Example: boolean realyCkecked = false;

```
In setOnCheckedChangeListener:
If(realyCkecked == false) {
    realyCkecked = true;
}
```

Then check that realyCkecked is true / false

```
If(realyCkecked) {
    System.out.println("Checked Atleast Once.");
} else {
    System.out.println("Not checked yet.");
}
```

So, you can know that even any time CheckBox is checked or not.

Answer (score 1):

This way u can have a boolean to see if ur checkbox is checked.

Use this in your java code.

```
CheckBox cb = findviewById(R.id.checkbox1);
if(cb.isChecked()){
          //it is checked 
}
//else it is not checked
```

Comment: You can call this whenever there is an onCheckedChange in your listener

Answer (score 0):

In your `setOnCheckedChangeListener()` method you can take a counter and increment it. After that, where you want to use it you compare it with your previous value.